# Debian, mysql: How can I tune these values

Tags: mysql, apache, apache2, debian

I have a debian VPS with 16 GB ram (CPU: 4 * 2Ghz).

I notice some performance issues when I now have about 2,000 request / seconds.

The CPU is at:

```
41% user, 8% kernel, 2% IO, 49% idle
```

and ram:

```
15.71 GB total, 4.97 GB used
```

I'm a complete noob when it comes to servers, so I dont want to mess around to much. I notice a performance increase when raising max_connections from 1,000 to 2,000, and increased key_buffer from 512 to 1024M.

If anyone could take a look at the values below, and let me know if there's any tweaks I can do, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance:

```
    # * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 1024M
max_allowed_packet  = 512M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 2000
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 32M
query_cache_size        = 128M
```

Comment: mysql tuning is not obvious process which **strictly** depends on the nature of software that uses it. So there is no silver bullet set up

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand. I figure if you could see anything obvious that could be tuned?

Comment: max_connections seems kind of high. What specifically do you mean when you say you get a "performance increase" with that high value? What OS and architecture? InnoDB or MyISAM? What percentage is writes vs. reads? A lot of inserts? What's your major pain/complaint?

Answer (score 3):

First of all: Make a backup of your my.cnf to go back if anything goes wrong.

Then use [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl) to give you some basic information about your database and some tuning advice. Before you make changes be sure to refer to the mysql documentation what the setting actually does and evaluate if it (seems) to make sense. Then apply the changes and run mysqltuner again after 24+h to see the changes